# I am using Kinvey as my backend for my Android Application

Tags: android, macos, kinvey

[gradle build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qq2Ak.png)

I followed these steps to set it up: http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/getting-started

I am getting an error which says:

"FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

  > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/kinvey/android/AbstractAsyncUser$1.class
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED"

I already changed compile(name:'kinvey-android-*', ext:'aar') to compile(name:'kinvey-android-2.10.5', ext:'aar')

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you post your bulid.gradle

Comment: Hey, i just uploaded an image of build.gradle

Comment: @AishwaryaGagadam can you try the build with Kinvey SDK 2.10.4 available here - http://download.kinvey.com/Android/kinvey-android-2.10.4.zip

Answer (score 2):

If you have two or more `java-api-core-x.y.z.jar` in your libs folder, remove the oldest releases and keep the last version.

In my case I had `java-api-core-2.10.5.jar` and `java-api-core-2.10.1.jar`, I have removed `java-api-core-2.10.1.jar`.

It makes sense because there are two versions of the same library.